# What does `Dict[str, Any]` mean in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, function, annotations

I'm referring to the documentation available [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) to understand how the return types are defined while using function annotations.

I couldn't understand what the str in `Dict[str, Any]` refers to. Does `str` refer to the dictionary's keys and `Any` (meaning, it can be a string or an int) refer to the type of the dictionary's value? 
EDIT:
In the above-mentioned link, it is mentioned

> The PEP 484 type Dict[str, Any] would be suitable, but it is too
>   lenient, as arbitrary string keys can be used, and arbitrary values
>   are valid.

Could someone explain what does `arbitrary string keys` refer to? I understand keys are strings, but when we say `arbitrary string keys` do we just mean that the dictionary can take any key that is a string? Or does the word `arbitrary` hold any other significance here?

Comment: Yes, you have understood it correctly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yep! Normally python variables are mutable (types can change), but specifying it like this is good documentation and makes it very clear what goes where.

More usage documentation can be found here! https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

### EDIT: Elaborate on answer on updated question

The [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/) documentation you refer to identifies how type-hints, albeit useful, are still error prone.

By specifying `Dict[str, Any]`, the `str` can be "`arbitrary`", meaning it can be a string key of anything (ie. `name`, `age`, `height`, `humidity`). Out of these keys, one may consider "`humidity`" shouldn't be one of the string-keys for this `dict`, but there isn't a way to check, or enforce that until some error occurs down the road (hence, it is "arbitrary"; no rules to govern what are "allowed" string-keys of this `dict`).

Therefore, per the documentation, specifying this class (derived from `TypedDict`):

> ```
> class Movie(TypedDict):
>     name: str
>     year: int
> ```

will specifically limit users to create a new kind of `dict` (a `TypedDict`) with string-keys `name` and `year` (with respective values typed `str` and `int`). Users will not be able to "arbitrarily" add a new key (ie. `humidity`) to this "`Movie`" `TypedDict`, or otherwise assign a non-`int` value to `Movie["year"]`.